# Cryptic Encryption

Tags: cipher, cryptic-clues

This is fairly simple. Solve the 3 cryptics here to know how the 4th was encrypted. 
 Once you've done that, solve the 4th and that's the answer to this little puzzle.

Proclaim hazily, "dear cel"!(7)
Indiana and Delaware hanging free. (11)
Triumvirates of excursion permits(8)

> 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 6 4 1 7 5 1 16 2 1 17 8 1 18 5 1 21 3 1 24 3 1 27 6 1 36 2 1 45 3?
>   1 48 1 1 51 1 1 62 5 1 63 2 1 47 7 1 65 4 1 68 1 1 72 1 1 73 2 1 78 4 1 81 2 1 82 3 1 83 5 1 88 4 1 100 3 1 101 3 1 103 3 1 144 5 1 158 3 1 163 3 1 169 1! (5)

Comment: FIrst clue is easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The clues have answers

> DECLARE INDEPENDENT TRIPLETS.

Explanations:

> Anagram ("hazily") of "dear cel" meaning "proclaim"; IN + DE + PENDENT meaning "free"; TRIP + LETS meaning "triumvirates".

So I guess

> each set of three numbers is used to look something up in the Declaration of Independence; perhaps e.g. it's paragraph number, word number, letter number or something. The triples are (i,j,k) where i=1 always, j increases and gets as high as 169, and k is always fairly small.

This seems to work, kinda, if we

> ignore i, treat j as a (1-based) word index within the whole DoI, and treat k as a (1-based) character index within each word. (Where a word has an apostrophe, we keep it.)

The result is:

> What has no end? Gale's two feet of beluga! (5)

I take it this is a cryptic clue but I am still trying to work out the answer.

... But while I was thinking about it, Techidiot (in TSL) provided the answer:

> WHALE (WHA(t) + (ga)LE, and there is a beluga whale as well as the more famous beluga sturgeon).

Comment: Your second word is incorrect. The one you have is 12 letters and you need an 11 letter one. Although this is pretty much just pedantry

Comment: You know what? I wrote the correct one first and then "corrected" it to what you see now because that seemed more likely in view of what was obviously going to be done with the numbers :-). I'll fix it.

Comment: (I've fixed it now.)

Comment: Also, (when you get around to it/have time) could you explain the wordplay/definition of each cryptic?

Comment: @dcfyj Pedantry or pendentry?

Comment: Explanations added. My first attempt at indexing produced nonsense. Still thinking about it.